# Mysql - not inserting more than one row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a signup and login page. It worked fine for the first time, the data that i entered in signup form were inserted in my database. but when i was trying for the second time , mysql is not entering the data into the table. I tried several times, but the table shows only one row and its not inserting more row.

This is the code for inserting the data into database

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array();

// connect to the data base
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');


// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
// receive all input values from the form
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
$password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
$password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

// form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
// by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); 
 }
if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
 }

// first check the database to make sure
// a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($user) { // if user exists
if ($user['username'] === $username) {
  array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
}

if ($user['email'] === $email) {
  array_push($errors, "email already exists");
}
}

/ / Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
if (count($errors) == 0) {
$password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database

$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
          VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
header('location: profile.php');
 }
}

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

if (empty($username)) {
array_push($errors, "Username is required");
}
if (empty($password)) {
array_push($errors, "Password is required");
}

if (count($errors) == 0) {
$password = md5($password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
  header('location: profile.php');
}else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
}
 }
}

?>
```

The Html code for the form:

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>

 ///...

  <body>
  <div class="form">

  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup">
      <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

      <form action="register.php" method="post">
        <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            User Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"required autocomplete="off" />
        </div>



      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password_1" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>
      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Set A Password Again<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password_2" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="reg_user"/>Get Started</button>

      </form>

    </div>

    <div id="login">
      <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

      <form action="register.php" method="post">

       <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          User name<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" required autocomplete="off"/>
       </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password" name="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>


      <button class="button button-block" name="login_user"/>Log In</button>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->

 <script  src="register.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Could get some help regarding this problem, kindly check and help me with a solution

Comment: Two obvious things first: You're vulnerable to sql injection so please use prepared statements! And please don't use md5 for password hashing. md5 isn't secure enough. PHP has the built in methods `password_hash` and `password_verfiy` for secure password handling.

Comment: @LLJ97 thanks for the suggestion, i will make those changes, but does it affect the insertion of data into database

Comment: No it doesn't but a lot of people are still not aware of this so it's always a good thing to remind them instead of letting them live in a false sense of security.
I'm still looking through your code. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Euhm I dont know if you made this code or not, but are you sure you're not using the same username/email to register for the second time? Cause this code checks that. Or maybe the 2 passwords dont match?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with that `$error` array. Could be nice to use it to make sure you have no errors

Comment: This looks similar to a problem I had with a database of mine and has nothing to do with the PHP (as you already noted, it works on first try, just not after), but with how you defined your database. I can think of two problems: 1) the primary key you defined is not AUTO_INCREMENT (duplicate problems). 2) A row that shouldn't be unique is set to unique. E.g., the password row.

Comment: @Loko i didnt use same name or email , the paswords match but then it doesnt show any errors, but when i check my table, the data is not entered

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Make sure the insert is actually running when signing up the second time, if it is, check if mysqli_query is returning a success, if not, check [mysqli_error](http://php.net/mysqli_error) to get the error message. If it's not hitting the insert code, work your way back until you find what code it is hitting and why the logic you're expecting isn't occurring.

Comment: @TimB It worked now, the problem was with the auto increment. the Id was not auto incremented.

Comment: @LLJ97 but isn't it enough to use " mysqli_real_escape_string" to prevent the sql injection

Comment: @vigneshu No it isn't. There are some methods to get through the escape function so the best way to be secure is to use prepared statements.

Comment: @vignesh u Will write a matching answer, then. Please accept it if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

As I already suggested in the comments, problems like this one where one row inserts fine, then the next one doesn't usually have to do with
- Your primary key row not being `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which leads to duplicate primary keys and the new inserts getting rejected (was the problem here)
- Or a row that's not supposed to be unique getting defined as unique (for example setting the password row to unique is a bad idea).

It has nothing to do with the PHP, but is something you need to fix in your database. If you use PHPMyAdmin, then check the a_i checkbox for your primary key, and make sure rows which are supposed to have an index but aren't supposed to be unique or primary keys are set to INDEX.

In plain SQL, use the `AUTO_INCREMENT` keyword as in `CREATE TABLE whatever (ID INT(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT);`. As for creating appropriate indexes in MySQL, have a look at [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) and avoid the keyword unique if it's causing trouble.